# Error while changing font color in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have got problem. When i am writing this code to change font color based of plus or minus number i am getting error

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

I tried everything but it doesnt work. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Code for the component with numbers in table:

```
<td className="">
                    {props.coins.map(coins => {
                        
                        if (coins.price_change_percentage_24h > 0) {
                            var x = document.getElementById('percent')
                            x.style.color = 'red'
                        } else {
                            var x = document.getElementById('percent')
                            x.style.color = 'green'
                        }

                        return (
                            <div id='percent' className="flex flex-col border-b py-6 h-[73px] mx-[-2px] px-2">
                                {coins.price_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2)}%
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </td>
```

I tried everything. Hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your real issue is your approach.  So lets forget about your syntactical errors, and approach this differently.

Just use an inline style with a ternary argument.  You are overcomplicating it with if statements and query selectors.

```
props.coins.map(coins => {
        return (
            <div id='percent'
                 className="flex flex-col border-b py-6 h-[73px] mx-[-2px] px-2"
                 style={{
                 color: (coins.price_change_percentage_24h > 0) ? "red" : "green"
                 }}>
                {coins.price_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2)}%
            </div>
        )
    }
);
```

Comment: ```<div id="percent" className=`flex flex-col ... ${coins.price_change_percentage_24h > 0 ? "text-red-500" : "text-green-500"}`>...</div>```

Is also a possible solution if you want to keep it pure Tailwind.

Answer (score -1):

[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRG18.png)

you should try to use style attribute like this one. I think it will work. Like this:

style = { (coins.price_change_percentage_24h > 0) ? { color: "red" } : { color: "green" } }